# HTML table width discrepancy

Tags: html, css, html-table

The last row of [this chart](http://jsfiddle.net/hCj9J/) I have created using collapsed html tables is shorter by a few pixels despite all having same width. Why is that so ? Is there a better a way to create the chart without using multiple tables ?

```
<table cellpadding="0" style="padding-right:0px;padding-left:0px;width:800px;border-top:solid 1px;border-right:solid 1px;border-left:solid 1px;border-collapse:collapse;table-layout:fixed"><tr>
<td style="text-align:center;width:100px;height:25px;border-right:solid 1px;">User</td>
<td style="text-align:center;width:600px;height:25px;border-right:solid 1px;">300 Gb</td>
<td style="text-align:center;width:100px;height:25px;border-right:solid 1px;">Usage (Gb)</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table cellpadding="0" style="padding-right:0px;padding-left:0px;width:800px;border-top:solid 1px;border-right:solid 1px;border-left:solid 1px;border-collapse:collapse;table-layout:fixed"><tr>
<td style="text-align:center;width:100px;height:25px;border-right:solid 1px;">user1</td>
<td style="background-color:#FF0000;width:436px;height:25px;"></td>
<td style="background-color:#D22A00;width:54px;height:25px;"></td>
<td style="background-color:#A85400;width:1px;height:25px;"></td>
<td style="background-color:#7F7F00;width:12px;height:25px;"></td>
<td style="width:97px;border-right:solid 1px;"></td>
<td style="width:100px;text-align:center;">252.69</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table cellpadding="0" style="padding-right:0px;padding-left:0px;width:800px;border-top:solid 1px;border-right:solid 1px;border-left:solid 1px;border-collapse:collapse;table-layout:fixed"><tr>
<td style="text-align:center;width:100px;height:25px;border-right:solid 1px;">user2</td>
<td style="background-color:#FF0000;width:344px;height:25px;"></td>
<td style="width:256px;border-right:solid 1px;"></td>
<td style="width:100px;text-align:center;">172.15</td>
</tr>
</table>

<table cellpadding="0" style="padding-right:0px;padding-left:0px;text-align:center;width:800px;border-top:solid 1px;border-bottom:solid 1px;border-right:solid 1px;border-left:solid 1px;border-collapse:collapse;table-layout:fixed"><tr>
<td style="height:25px;width:114px;background-color:#FF0000">&gt;32 days</td>
<td style="height:25px;width:114px;background-color:#D22A00">&lt;32 days</td>
<td style="height:25px;width:114px;background-color:#A85400">&lt;16 days</td>
<td style="height:25px;width:114px;background-color:#7F7F00">&lt;8 days</td>
<td style="height:25px;width:114px;background-color:#54A800">&lt;4 days</td>
<td style="height:25px;width:114px;background-color:#2AD200">&lt;2 days</td>
<td style="height:25px;width:116px;background-color:#00FF00">&lt;1 days</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: you really should add some CSS styling so that each thing isn't labeled with `style="height:25px; width:114px;"` etc. etc. (just for readability)

Comment: `inline styles` are a pain in the arse to modify and read. FYI.

Comment: Luxelin It is auto-generated code and was not meant to be read or hand edited.

Comment: This should really be 1 table, with the legend possibly being a separate div.  E.g. your first table is simply the `<thead>`.

Comment: But, to fix the problem (BTW, I would not use tables to create graphs, but I digress) remove the hard-coded width in at least one of the TD's in each row. That will allow that TD to have some 'wiggle room' so that it can obey the table's width setting.

Comment: DA - What is the alternative to create a html graph ?

Answer (score 1):

With container elements, their width / height is measured not including padding, margins, and borders (thanks @davidpauljunior) by default. Set `box-sizing: border-box` attribute of your elements to ensure they line up exactly by width / height specified, taking into account padding, margins and borders.

http://jsfiddle.net/hCj9J/1/

Comment: ...and not including borders, which was the issue here (borders on the `<td>` elements in the first tables)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're doing your math wrong or the extra borders are screwing with your numbers. You really aren't using tables or CSS classes effectively here. The point of using a table and not a bunch of divs is so you don't have to specify what each individual cell size should be. The display:table property it inherits does all that fancy stuff for you.

Make one single new table with 3 TDs in the first 2 rows, and 7 in the 3rd row. The third row will have all 7 TDs. For the first and second rows, you'll have a TD, then you'll have a TD with a colspan='5' followed by another TD.

Here's a basic example of colspans:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td colspan="2"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Then, you can give these cells or tows a class which you can use to color them with CSS, rather than giving each one its own style attribute.